# how to play custom notification sound using javascript on some other website

Tags: javascript, chatbot

I am trying to make a script that will notify me by playing a tone whenever some specific chat messages appear in the chat box.

This is for an online game site which rewards users with some coins every hour or so. They do it using a chat bot. That bot is only used to give away coins, and doesn't do anything else. It types out the same 2 messages which are: "Are you ready for free coins? click here (which is a captcha)" so if a user passes the captcha they are on the bot's list to give free coins. It then waits 2 mins for other players to enter, and after 2 minutes it shows how many coins you got if you didn't miss the giveaway. If you did miss then it shows: "X users got Y amount of coins".

Comment: We are not a code writing site. Show us what you have attempted so far. Are you using anything like chrome or firefox extensions?

Comment: This question is too broad. You better add code example and more details